# how to compress and minify assets using jekyll plugins

Tags: jekyll, minify

I have a simple test jekyll app like so:

index.html is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/myfile.js"><script>
<p>hi</p>
```

and the myfile.js files is as follows:

```
var  x  = "this is a string";
alert(x +  "hi");
```

I just want to add a plugin so that it can minify the js file before it is written to the _site/assets/myfile.js file

How can i achienve that?

Answer (score 15):

Here's a summary of what I've found while solving this in 2014:

Started with

1. https://github.com/donaldducky/jekyll-cssminify

   Development was going well until it was beat by this project:
2. http://www.matthodan.com/2012/11/22/jekyll-asset-pipeline.html

   ...which so far has been my favorite to implement, except it doesn't work now and it looks like development has been halted, so I was forced to turn to
3. https://github.com/envygeeks/jekyll-assets

   ...which again, beats #2 but is just a touch trickier to use.  Anyway, that's the only one that works, so that's what I'm using now.

Comment: Another +1 for jekyll-assets

Comment: Stupid question: how to use jekyll-assets to compress JS? I'm new to Jekyll and its docs sucks.

Comment: Hi @rilwis, no worries.  Been a while since I worked on this but it looks like right on the `readme` for Jekyll Assets there's a JS configuration object with a compression flag: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-assets#configuration

Comment: I come from the future and unfortunately jekyll-assets' development stopped in 2020.

Answer (score 5):

There are plugins for [HTML](https://github.com/stereobooster/html_press) and [CSS](https://github.com/donaldducky/jekyll-cssminify) minification with Jekyll, but a search doesn't turn up anything obvious for JS.

However, the [source for CSS one above](https://github.com/donaldducky/jekyll-cssminify/blob/master/CssMinify.rb) is less than 100 lines and actually uses [Juicer](https://github.com/cjohansen/juicer) to do the minification, which can also do JS, so that plugin could easily be used as a template to implement your own JS minifier (it looks like even just `s/css/js/g` would be close to working).

Answer (score 4):

I recommend the [Jekyll Asset Pipeline](http://www.matthodan.com/2012/11/22/jekyll-asset-pipeline.html) gem for this.  It supports any language (e.g. Scss, Less, CoffeeScript, Erb, etc.) and has a bunch of features (e.g. asset tagging, compression, gzipping, etc.) that set it apart. It also seems to be the fastest growing Jekyll-related gem these days, which I take to mean that it is gaining traction in the community.

Comment: I was enjoying using this but it looks like development has halted?  Using https://github.com/ixti/jekyll-assets for now.

Answer (score 3):

For JS and CSS you can use the [Jekyll Asset Bundler](https://github.com/moshen/jekyll-asset_bundler) It uses the yui-compressor or closure-compiler gems.

Answer (score 0):

For images, I made a drop-in plugin that runs the images through [image_optim](https://github.com/toy/image_optim):

https://gist.github.com/sffc/a828267913591159ab1cc3e1bfde20d7

Answer (score 0):

This one seems fairly updated as compared to other plugins and minifies HTML/XML/CSS/JS Minifier utilising yui-compressor, and htmlcompressor
https://github.com/digitalsparky/jekyll-minifier