# Is JS minification possible within jekyll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jekyll

I am working on a project using Jekyll and as a part of that, there is the need to minify HTML-CSS-JS. Is JS minification possible as in-build in jekyll? This might be a very basic question. But being a newbie to jekyll, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Google suggests that https://github.com/digitalsparky/jekyll-minifier and https://github.com/gjtorikian/jekyll-jsminify and https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/476 might be useful starting points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a plugin, AFAIK.

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22027282/2397550) you should use the [Jekyll Assets plugin](https://github.com/envygeeks/jekyll-assets).

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 0):

You can try use minifier that I recently developed https://github.com/Mendeo/jekyll-minifier. It is written purely on liquid, so you do not need to install any additional gems and it is fully compatible with GitHub Pages.